# How to get current PHP function name in gdb?

Tags: debugging, gdb, php

I'm following these [steps](https://bugs.php.net/bugs-generating-backtrace.php) to locate the current PHP function call as below:

1. Run dummy script:

   ```
   $ gdb -ex run --args php -r "sleep(10);"
   ```
2. Pressed <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> to get back to `gdb` to run:

   ```
   (gdb) bt full
   #1  0x00007ffff6007dd4 in __sleep (seconds=0) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/sleep.c:137
           ts = {tv_sec = 8, tv_nsec = 306649388}
           set = {__val = {65536, 0 <repeats 15 times>}}
           oset = {__val = {0, 4469319, 4294967295, 8081486, 140737319884960, 140737354070488, 15761488, 15454080, 15337134, 
               140737354001040, 0, 7307048, 16048064, 206158430232, 140737488342304, 140737488342096}}
           result = <optimized out>
   #2  0x00000000006156ef in zif_sleep ()
   No symbol table info available.
   #3  0x00000000006ddd7b in dtrace_execute_internal ()
   No symbol table info available.
   #4  0x000000000079dde5 in ?? ()
   No symbol table info available.
   #5  0x0000000000717b18 in execute_ex ()
   No symbol table info available.
   #6  0x00000000006ddc79 in dtrace_execute_ex ()
   No symbol table info available.
   #7  0x00000000006e1b0a in zend_eval_stringl ()
   No symbol table info available.
   #8  0x00000000006e1bf9 in zend_eval_stringl_ex ()
   ...
   (gdb) frame 2
   #2  0x00000000006156ef in zif_sleep ()
   (gdb) print (char *)(executor_globals.function_state_ptr->function)->common.function_name
   Attempt to extract a component of a value that is not a structure.      
   (gdb) print (char *)(executor_globals.function_state_ptr->function)
   Attempt to extract a component of a value that is not a structure.
   (gdb) print (char *)(executor_globals)
   $2 = 0xffffffffffffcf48 <error: Cannot access memory at address 0xffffffffffffcf48>
   ```

   So it seems `executor_globals` symbol is not available. Is it because the binary has been optimized, I'm in the wrong frame or something else? Or I should use `lldb` instead?

Comment: If the symbol was unavailable, you'd get a different error message, about an unknown symbol. (Try `print (char *) (blarflgrumpf)`). This seems like your binary has been compiled with optimization on (which could put some variables into registers, without `gdb` knowing, and relying on the (wrong) stack value). Try to compile/link `php` with `-O0` and `-g`. Also, unless you cut some parts of the backtrace, your stack is probably broken, as `execute_ex` seems to have been called out of thin air. This broken stack may be the reason for all sorts of unexpected behaviour.

Comment: @GuntramBlohm Thanks, yes, there are more frames in bt (up to #10 with ??), I've re-added. Yes, unknown symbol is printing different message. So that means I can't access/extract that data about the current function without re-compiling the PHP?

Comment: Well, some things seem a bit fishy to me: the instructions tell you to move the frame to the last `execute` call, while you only have `execute_ex`; if `executor_globals` is indeed a global variable, the stack frame shouldn't matter, but if it's local, you shouldn't find it in the `zif_sleep` frame. I wonder how up-to-date the site is you linked to. But as the value of `executor_globals` is wrong, and your PHP site says "Important!
To get a backtrace with correct information you must have PHP configured with --enable-debug! ", I think you need to recompile.

Comment: Highly relevant https://stackoverflow.com/a/31240030/308851

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [this link](https://derickrethans.nl/what-is-php-doing.html), it should be possible to find the function in use with the following steps:

1. Attach gdb to the currently-running PHP process: `gdb -p <processid>`
2. Load in the PHP `.gdbinit` file for your version of PHP (available from [here](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/.gdbinit))
3. Use the `zbacktrace` command to display the currently-running PHP script

For example:

```
gdb -p 4584
(gdb) source PHP_5_5/.gdbinit
(gdb) zbacktrace
[0xec906090] addOne() /tmp/yourscript.php:9
```

Comment: Awesome! The link in 2. to the .gdbinit file helped a lot! Thanks!

Comment: This link was also useful for me to install `php5-cli-dbgsym` https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingProgramCrash